# MVC Model doesnt support ToPagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have  a model like this

```
public class SearchVM
{
    [DisplayName("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Beds")]
    public string NumberOfBeds { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Baths")]
    public string NumberOfBaths { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prices From")]
    public string PriceFrom { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prices To")]
    public string PriceTo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Rental> Rentals { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Rental> FeatureRentals { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Sale> FeatureSales { get; set; }
    public Rental NewRentals { get; set; }
    public Sale NewSales { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller when trying to use this model SearchVM i cannot use the ToPagedList method

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchVM searchvm, int page = 1)
{      
    var query = from c in context.Rentals
                select c;

    searchvm.Rentals = query;

    return View("RentProperty", query.ToPagedList(page,9));
}
```

I noticed that searchvm.ToPagedList doesnt work. Can some one please help

Comment: Do you have a paging library installed?

Comment: Also the line `searchvm.Rentals = query;` is probably pointless.

Comment: Agree with @DavidG. `ToPageList()` is not part of the standard ASP.NET MVC, it's more likely to be an extension method written by a third-party. Either you need to add a missing NuGet Package, or add the `using` statement that imports that method, if you already have the assembly for that extension method.

Comment: David i do have the the paging library installed thats why its working with query.ToPagedList(page,9). I was just wondering does searchvm model need to be specific type?

Comment: @kayze What do you expect to happen if you do `searchvm.ToPagedList(page, 9)`?

Answer (score 1):

You are either missing a library reference in your code or if you already have that, you need to add a relevant `using` statement. For example, you may need this at the top of your code:

```
using PagedList;
```

Without this line, the compiler doesn't know where to get the `ToPagedList()` extension method.

Comment: No i am not missing that name space. Its working for query.ToPagedList(page,9) but not searchvm.ToPagedList(page,9)

Comment: `SearchVM` isn't itself a collection class, only some of the properties are. You can do `searchvm.Rentals.ToPagedList()` for example.

Comment: how would i turn the whole searchvm to a collection? i just want this whole object/model to be of type IpagedList, because in the view it returns searchvm.rentals which are pagedlist

Comment: I'm  not sure you would want to do that. You could return an `IEnumerable<SearchVM>` but I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Comment: That should work,how could i convert my searchVM obkect to IEnumerable?

Comment: Do you REALLY want to return lots of `SearchVM` objects?

Comment: No. But my model searchvm seems to only accept the pagedlist method when its ienumerable

Comment: Don't you simply want to page the **properties** of searchvm rather than the model itself?

Comment: I want the model. The view thats gets called from this control is of type IpagedList, that lists the searchvm.rentals as paged items. There is also a partial view inside the view which uses the searchvm properties (noOfBaths, NoOfRooms, etc)

Comment: Then change the view.

Comment: To WHat? at the moment it takes rentals as the model (as the code i pasted show), but this wouldnt work for my partial view as it needs the properties of searchvm

Comment: Well the parent view shouldn't take an IEnumerable anything, it should take a plain SearchVM.

Comment: thanks but we're back to square one. plain searchVM is not IEnumerable and is not taking ToPagedList method

Comment: No, you page the individual properties.

Comment: Example? for example searchvm.Rentals.ToPageList requires rentals model. If i want to pass searchvm from controller i cant paged the rentals properties